# Filter collection via linq based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have collection that i want to filter based on `multiple criteria`.

That's my filter class:

```cs
class CriteriaClass {
    public DertEnum? DertEnum { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    CriteriaClass() {
        DertEnum = null;
        UserName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My question is how to say here that if `criteriaClass.DertEnum`  is null not to include it in linq filter. Same for `criteriaClass.UserName` if it's `empty`. How to use to not go into `if/else.` I am sure there is a way.

```cs
_data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(_data.Where(w =>
    (w.DertEnum.Equals(EnumTools.T(criteriaClass.WarehouseActionTypeEnum)))
    && (w.UserName.Equals(criteriaClass.UserName))));
```

Comment: Use logical and, `&&`, and logical or, `||`, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if something is not `null`, you can use `is object`. To check if a string is null or empty, you can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` :

```
_data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(_data.Where(w => w.DertEnum is object
                                                           && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(w.UserName)
                                                           && (<your other criterias go there>)))
```

Comment: Something not working, second criteria or even first criteria or both has to be checked depending on if DertEnum  is not null it has to be emdded into filter,  and/or w.UserName.Equals(criteriaClass.UserName) has to be included only when criteriaClass.UserName is not empty. With your code if DertEnum  is not null and criteriaClass.UserName is not empty then i get no result, if criteriaClass.UserName is empty it works . What is going on?

Comment: Did you forget to add the `!` in front of `String.IsNullOrEmpty(w.UserName)`

Answer (score 1):

Add a logical or is null check to the where criteria:

```
_data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(_data.Where(w =>
    ((w.DertEnum is null || w.DertEnum.Equals(EnumTools.T(criteriaClass.WarehouseActionTypeEnum))))
    && (w.UserName.Equals(criteriaClass.UserName))));
```

Comment: for second check shouldn;t be chec if string empty? I want only to pass that second criteria when criteriaClass.UserName is not string empty